# forward-button in page-tree in my typo3 backend

Tags: typo3

can you explain me this button in my typo3 backend-page-tree:

[image: forward-button in typo3 backend]

It looks like a forward-button. How can I make it disappear in the page-settings?

Thank you,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears when at `Access` tab in page properties you will check `Extend to Subpages` checkbox.